# WL 5.0.6.1 - Dialog "Unexpected response" (Reload,Close,Details) comes up at WL-Server Connection when on public WIFI Captive Portal / AuthPage

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

When our app is started up within a secured Wifi and the smartphone user did not authenticate with that Wifi Login/Captive Portal yet, the WL.Client.connect as well as connectOnStartup receive the HTML page of the portal for their connection request.

It seems the process/WL Framework is not stable in such a situation (see below). The problem is that the App **does not end up in the onSuccess or onFailure** procedures that we passed in as options object - there is a default Dialog being shown by Cordova/Worklight to the end user. This dialog even allows to view details of the request and the app environment.

So far, we did not find any event or hook to capture such an error situation.

**( UPDATE Sept. 18: in the iOS native Objective-C WL Client Library this behavior is not the same - there: the onSuccess method is called in case of WL.Client.connect and the onFailure in case of invokeProcedure )**

**Does anyone know how we could catch this error/exception?**

[image]

[image]

```
09-05 10:27:48.526: D/App(8590): ondeviceready event dispatched
09-05 10:27:48.546: D/App(8590): wlclient init started
09-05 10:27:48.546: D/App(8590): Read cookies: null
09-05 10:27:48.546: D/App(8590): CookieMgr read cookies: {}
09-05 10:27:48.566: D/App(8590): before: app init onSuccess
09-05 10:27:48.566: D/App(8590): in startBusyIndicator
09-05 10:27:48.566: D/App(8590): busyIndicator is null or not visible, so create and show
09-05 10:27:48.566: D/App(8590): Exiting startBusyIndicator: [object Object]
09-05 10:27:48.566: D/App(8590): Call WL.Client.connect establish connection and trigger the direct update check
09-05 10:27:48.576: D/App(8590): Request [http://XXX:8080/apps/services/api/App/android/init]
09-05 10:27:48.596: D/App(8590): after: app init onSuccess
09-05 10:27:48.596: D/App(8590): wlclient init success
09-05 10:27:48.637: E/external/webkit/Source/WebKit/android/WebCoreSupport/WebRequest.cpp(8590): startReading called with a nonzero buffer
09-05 10:27:48.637: E/external/webkit/Source/WebKit/android/WebCoreSupport/WebRequest.cpp(8590): Read called with a nonzero buffer
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590): response [http://XXX:8080/apps/services/api/App/android/init] success: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590): <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590): <head>
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590): <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590): <title>Untitled Document</title>
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590): <style type="text/css">
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590):         
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590):               <p align="center"><strong>App </strong><strong>HotSpot WiFi Access</strong></p>
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590):               <div id="center_this">
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590):                 
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590):                 <div id="rules_window">
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590):                 
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590): 
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590):                 <p align=center style='text-align:center'><b>Terms of Use</b></p>
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590):                             <p>NOTICE: PLEASE READ CAREFULLY. THE FOLLOWING CONSTITUTES</p>
09-05 10:27:48.667: D/App(8590):                       
09-05 10:27:48.687: E/App(8590): [http://XXX:8080/apps/services/api/App/android/init] exception. Cannot read property 'userInfo' of null
09-05 10:27:48.857: V/webview(8590): SCROLL_TO_MSG_ID
09-05 10:27:48.857: V/webcore(8590): CLEAR_HISTORY arg1=0 arg2=0 obj=null
09-05 10:27:48.927: D/CordovaLog(8590): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userInfo' of null
09-05 10:27:48.927: E/Web Console(8590): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userInfo' of null at file:///data/data/com.App/files/www/default/wlclient/js/worklight.js:1487
09-05 10:27:50.489: D/DroidGap(8590): onMessage(spinner,stop)
```

Comment: technically its not a failure, because you are getting a response from the end point, its just not the response that worklight is expecting.  you can override the onSuccess of the client.connect by passing it as optiion, ,from what i see in the code in wlclient.js

Comment: I am sorry that I was not clear enough (I edited this part) ... of course, we give both procedures to the client.connect - a onSuccess and a onFailure ... none of them is being called before the dialog is shown by Worklight. The "wlclient init success" debug is printed by worklight. Our debug print in our onSuccess and onFailure would be `app.DebugLog("WL.Client.connect success/failure");`

Comment: Yes i see it now, its going through its own onSuccess before passing off to yours.  The first line of code in that onConnectSuccess is what is giving you the dialog.         function onConnectSuccess(transport) {
            if (transport == null || transport.responseJSON == null) {
                WL.SimpleDialog.show(WL.ClientMessages.error, WL.ClientMessages.responseNotRecognized, [ {
                    text : WL.ClientMessages.ok
                } ]);
            }....     you might have to override the prototype

Comment: how would we do that? since they are in the scope of wl.client.connect(), how would you override something but still call the original functionality? There is also the handleDirectUpdate in that scope that we would like to override with additional functionality as well.

Comment: in my opinion it does not make any sense that worklight is showing a dialog in this code `function onConnectSuccess(transport) {if (transport == null || transport.responseJSON == null) {showDialog(WL.ClientMessages.error,WL.ClientMessages.responseNotRecognized, true, true, {}, WL.ClientMessages.responseNotRecognized);}` .... In my opinion a call to options.onFailure would be the right implementation, then we could easily catch that error and implement exception handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a challenge handler that will take care of your login form. See this training module - http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/08_02_Form_based_authentication.pdf

The only difference is that login form returned by your gateway and not WL server, but from client perspective it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Also, you can try adding onConnectionFailure callback to initOptions

Comment: just to clarify ... this is not "my" login form or "my" gateway, this is the case if the app end-user is on any random airport or company Wifi and receives a Captive Portal HTML page when he browses to any random website. Of course, this also happens to the WL app, because it also "browses" to a website - the WL server ...  but we will see if we can build a "catch all" workaround with a challenge handler to catch ALL captive portal cases in all Wifi networks on the planet that could come up for an end-user!

Comment: onConnectionFailure is already in initOptions - does not get called.

Comment: I think this is a special case that the WL framework should be able to catch on it's own and nicely call the options.onFailure or any other procedure that we as developers provide. Not show a WL dialog that a end-user should never be seeing.

Comment: in getting started samples there's one showing integration with SiteMinder gateway. You can try taking this approach.

Comment: we will look into that, thank you. But nevertheless, every single Worklight application that connects to the WL server is prone to such an "unexpected response" if the developers do not build such a workaround for the "public WIFI authentication/captive portal" case. I think this should be made more clearly communicated in an extra Sample or Getting Started module or so? I don't see any way to simply not make a standard Wl app prone to that.

Comment: In the iOS native Objective-C WL Client Library this behavior is not the same - there: the onSuccess method is called in case of WL.Client.connect (probably because a Status:200 is considered a success) and the onFailure in case of invokeProcedure (probably because a Status:200 is not enough and it looks for something more) - There it is not necessary to implement a ChallengeHandler to catch this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint of Anton, we experimented with challenge handlers. Unfortunately the whole ChallengeHandler documentation is missing in the WL InfoCenter 5.0.6.1 http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp and 6.0 http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/

The requirement is to build a "Catch All" work-around for all "Captive Portal", "Authentication Portal", "Proxy Redirect" etc. cases in which HTML code is returned to the app by a proxy/gateway/etc instead of a valid/expected response from the WL server that the app is trying to call. It needs to work for all cases that a WL app could encounter on any WIFI network worldwide (business, airport, public, hotels etc). In any of these cases the connection to the WL server at "Connect" as well as at "InvokeProcedure" would receive HTML code and the WL default dialog would be shown if not caught.

Based on the example we added the following code to our initOptions.js:

```
var LoginFormChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler();

LoginFormChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
    WL.Logger.debug("isCustomResponse");

    if (!response || response.responseText === null) {
        WL.Logger.debug("ChallengeHandler :: null");
        return false;
    }

    if ((response.status == 200) && (response.responseText.indexOf("/*-secure-") === -1)) {
        WL.Logger.debug("ChallengeHandler :: received");
        app.handleChallenge(response);
        return true;
    } else {
        WL.Logger.debug("ChallengeHandler :: no received");
        return false;
    }

};

LoginFormChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function(response) {    
    WL.Logger.debug("ChallengeHandler :: handleChallenge");
};
```

and to our app.js

```
 app.handleChallenge = function(response){
        app.stopBusyIndicator();
        if(document.URL.indexOf("App.html") !== -1){            
            app.onServerRequestFailed(function(){$.mobile.changePage(app.getInitialPage());});
        }else{
            var options = app.stack.pop();
             if (options.suppressAlertOnConnectionFailure) {
                 if (options.onFailure)
                     options.onFailure(response);
             }else{
                 if (options.onFailure)
                     app.onServerRequestFailed(options.onFailure(response));
                 else
                     app.onServerRequestFailed();
             }
        }   
    };
```

We have not tested this code in a production environment yet and made several assumptions that could be invalid:

- we are checking for the **"/*-secure-"** string value in the response that is received. So far we have not been seeing any valid WL server response that does not contain this string. But it could be the case that there are WL server responses without that string, then this workaround would break and a valid response would be considered as invalid and would be handled as error/exception.
- we are handling the error/exception using our **app.handleChallenge** function already in the **isCustomResponse** function and not in the **LoginFormChallengeHandler.handleChallenge** function. This is due that we need to catch **Wl.Client.connect, connectOnStartup as well as invokeProcedure** error/exception cases. In our trials, the **LoginFormChallengeHandler.handleChallenge** function was only called in the **Wl.Client.connect, connectOnStartup** cases and not in the **invokeProcedure** case. (see follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879189/wl-5-0-6-1-js-vs-ios-native-handlechallenge-only-called-at-first-communicat)
- When returning **true** in the **isCustomResponse** function the original execution thread of **Wl.Client.connect, connectOnStartup and invokeProcedure** is stopped and **only** the **isCustomResponse** function (and in the **Wl.Client.connect, connectOnStartup** case also the **handleChallenge** function) is executed. This means that the developer provided **onSuccess or onFailure** are never called and all handling needs to be done in these challenge handler functions. Our solution was to **push** our created **Options Object** before we **invokeProcedure** onto a global JavaScript Array stack and **pop** that from the stack in our **app.handleChallenge** function to call **options.onFailure(response)** manually ourselves. We assume that the sequence of calls and response returns of our WL server calls stay in sync - otherwise this stack-based solution would break.

This solution might not be the best and recommended solution for this workaround, but since the WL framework does not handle such cases at all it might be a good approach to start with.

Of course, if your app actually has a login form and needs an actual challenge handler it gets more complicated to catch your own login form before catching all other WIFI redirect cases!